# Palette toolbar in Eclipse turned black

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]

As you can see, my palette toolbar turned black. It happened last night. I was changing the i.d. of my ImageView, and then Eclipse suddenly crashed. When I opened it again, the palette toolbar turned black, and as you can see, the textField (editText) turned into a box type textField instead of an underline.

Can someone help me solve this? I am required to use the underline `editText`.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `Theme.Light` theme from `AppTheme` dropdown.

[image]